# How to clear Subitem's text after listview.clone in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, listview

I'm cloning row with a button's click:

```
   Private Sub Button6_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button6.Click
    ListView2.Items.Add(ListView2.Items(ListView2.FocusedItem.Index).Clone())
End Sub
```

ALl is good except Subitem(4).text, i want to make it equals 0 when copied row added

```
   ListView2.Items(ListView2.FocusedItem.Index).SubItems(4).Text = 0
```

here i dont know what to replace instead of ListView2.FocusedItem.Index

Comment: Have you learned about variables? Use one. Assign the new item to a variable and then you can access it as many times as you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a variable to keep a reference to the cloned ListViewItem:

```
Dim lvwNew As ListViewItem = ListView2.Items(ListView2.FocusedItem.Index).Clone()
lvwNew.SubItems(4).Text = "0"
ListView2.Items.Add(lvwNew)
```

Comment: Perfect, So simple. Thanks a lot mate :)

Comment: No worries. Happy programming!